# Angular $http.post IE9 Access Is Denied Issue

Tags: angularjs, ajax, http

I am facing some issue in IE9 with angular $http.post with cros headers. i checked with other browsers its working even its also working in IE10. it would be great is some one can help me to get rid from this issue.

Thanks in advenced

Comment: Can you post your exact error message?? and did you enabled CORS in your WebApi?

Comment: Yes please, Cors  are enabled and working well in other browsers.
error message : Script5 : Access is denied

Comment: Read this go through the check list https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie